# iOS keyboard events in Adobe PhoneGap Build

Tags: cordova

Are there keyboard events in Adobe PhoneGap Build? Or a plugin that will expose them. Specifically I want to attach a callback to the keyboard showing and hiding.

I'm currently using focus and blur events on my inputs, but I'd rather be listening to the keyboard itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin to help you with this issue: https://github.com/mhweiner/CordovaiOSKeyboardPlugin

It basically lets you do stuff like this:

```
// See if keyboard is open or not
var is_open = Keyboard.isOpen();

// Get height of open keyboard (including inputAccessoryView toolbar)
var height = Keyboard.getHeight();

// The following jQuery events are available:
// keyboardWillShow, keyboardDidShow, keyboardWillHide, keyboardDidHide

// Set callback
$('body').on('keyboardWillShow', myCallback);

// Remove callback
$('body').off('keyboardWillShow');
```

Instructions can be found in the readme file wihtin the git repo.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the ionic keyboard on plain Cordova but is also available for phonegap build [here](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/793) and it worked like charm on android but it's multiplatfrom and works both on android and ios Plus some extra features for iOS but the feature you want is multiplatform:
after adding this on your config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.ionic-for-phonegap.keyboard" version="0.0.1" />
```

then use this on device ready:

```
//add event listeners
window.addEventListener('native.showkeyboard', keyboardShowFunction);
window.addEventListener('native.hidekeyboard', keyboardHideFunction);

//the handlers
//here if you want keyboard height use e.keyboardHeight in keyboardShowFunction to get it
function keyboardShowFunction(e){
    alert('Keyboard is on');
}

function keyboardHideFunction(e){
    alert('key board is off');
}
```

more features described on [github](https://github.com/vitohe/ionic-plugins-keyboard/tree/f94842fec1bacf72107083d2e44735e417e8439)